# How can I replace the content of a div instead append a value using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, javascript-framework

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following problem.

I have create this JQuery function that when the user select a file into an input tag having **id=rendicontoAllegato** it put the name of this file into an hidden div having **id=nomeDocumentoRendicontazione** into my page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#rendicontoAllegato").change(function() {
        alert("DOCUMENTO dopo selezione: " + $("#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione").text());

        var selectedFileName = $("#rendicontoAllegato").val();

        $('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').append(selectedFileName);

    });
 });
```

It works fine but the only problem is that if I first select something as**file1.txt** and then select another file as **file2.txt** into the div having **id=nomeDocumentoRendicontazione** I will have the concatenation of the 2 files name.

So I will have something like **file1.txtfile2.txt** and it is not good for me.

How can I replace the value of the div having **id=nomeDocumentoRendicontazione** instead to append a new value inside it?

Comment: You can use `.html()` or `.text()` or `.empty().append()` or `.empty().prepend()`  .... https://www.google.co.uk/search?btnG=1&q=jquery+set+content+of+div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) fn if you are dealing with with your data to be inserted as text or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) fn if you are dealing with html to be replaced

`$('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').text(selectedFileName);`

Or

`$('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').html(selectedFileName);`

Answer (score 3):

Use html() instead of append().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#rendicontoAllegato").change(function() {
        alert("DOCUMENTO dopo selezione: " + $("#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione").text());

        var selectedFileName = $("#rendicontoAllegato").val();

        $('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').html(selectedFileName);

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
 $('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').html(selectedFileName);
```

it will replace the already present HTML of that. OR you can use

```
 $('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').text(selectedFileName);
```

it will do the same but append your data as text.